# How to solve such a set of congruency?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I came across a question like this having multiple sets of congruency where a value was congruent to $1 \pmod n$ and then at last it was a multiple of $k$. So, was thinking if there is any general way to solve this without going through every line, finding a value of $a$ and inputting that into the next line when we know the value of $k$?
$$\left\{\begin{array}{c}
a\equiv 1\pmod 2\\
a\equiv 1\pmod 3\\
\vdots\\
a\equiv 1\pmod {k-1}\\
a\equiv 0\pmod k
\end{array}\right.$$

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible unless $k$ is prime, as a consequence of [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem). You probably want to use the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) for the general case.

Comment: If, we make k a prime then can it be generalised?